# Deselecting select option in Select2 jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using the select2 jquery plugin for select dropdown feature in web site. 
Every select box in not required to be selected for the form submission .
I want user to be able to deselect the selected option if he wants to. Is there any way I can achieve this using Select2 Plugin. Any Help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a blank option(option tag with blank value) in the select box for where you want the user to be able to deselect the value. In not sure what this has to do with select2.

If this doesn't solve you problem then let me know what options are you using to initialize select2 plugin or maybe elaborate more on the question.